# How do i resolve unable to access 'https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop.git/

Tags: error

I have cloned civicrm-buildkit-docker and started to create a dmaster demo site with `docker-compose exec -u buildkit civicrm civibuild create dmaster`

This will give me the below error

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop.git/': Could not resolve
>   host: github.com

I tried

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080, 
git config --global --unset http.proxy and 
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

They didn't work. How should i resolve this ?

Comment: Welcome to civicrm stackexchange. It can help others to answer your question if you provide more relevant details. Are you running this command on a server, your local computer using docker? That error message suggests the command is not connecting out to the internet. Are you able to manually use git to clone that repo? i.e. git clone https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop.git/

Comment: @LukeStewart Thank you for your comment. as you said there was a connection problem. now it's working fine :)